# Cannot find array after creation - Java

Tags: java, arrays, netbeans, variable-assignment

I'm making a basic program that requires the use of all the letters' indices in the alphabet. I made an array and tried to add something to it, but NetBeans keeps saying that it "cannot find symbol: class "alphabet"". My code is similar to the following:

```
public class MyClass {
    char[] alphabet = new char[26];
    alphabet[0] = 'a';
    // et cetera
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Stuff
    }
}
```

Any ideas as to why NetBeans says no to the above? My bet is that I've gotten something very basic wrong, but I just can't figure out what...

Edit: as requested, a more comprehensive code is posted. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: The part of the code you provided is not enough for us.

Comment: What is the context of this code? You need a class and a method.

Comment: Please, lose a lot of your precious time to add more details!

Comment: There is no code in my main :o

Comment: In fact, move the char assignment in the main or in another method!

Comment: you cant access private class members from static class

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to place

alphabet[0] = 'a';

in a method or constructor not the class block.

Also it cannot be the main method as this is an instance variable. E.g.:

```
public class Alpha  {
    char[] alphabet = new char[26];

    public Alpha() {
        alphabet[0] = 'a';
    }

}
```

Comment: Just wondering, why is this so?

Comment: `alphabet` here is tied to a class instance. Only `static` variables can be accessed from `main` without creating an instance. Raw assignments are statements and can only appear inside code blocks.

Answer (score 5):

Move the lines inside a method. For instance in `main` for the beginning.

Answer (score 4):

The statement

```
alphabet[0] = 'a';
```

must appear in a block of code.

Try

```
char[] alphabet = new char[26];
{
    alphabet[0] = 'a';
}
```

or a better solution is

```
public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        char[] alphabet = new char[26];
        alphabet[0] = 'a';
        // et cetera
        // Stuff
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you're looking for an example of a fully written Java program, check out this post:

http://howtoprogramwithjava.com/java-tutorial-java-hello-world-part-ii/

The code you've posted isn't entirely correct, as you need to include the "meat" of the code inside of your 'main' method:

```
public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
      char[] alphabet = new char[26];
      alphabet[0] = 'a';
    }
}
```

Comment: I have deleted every single other bit of code, and it still doesn't work :o

Comment: Looks like you just need to move your code into the 'main' method, like so: public class MyClass {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        char[] alphabet = new char[26];
        alphabet[0] = 'a';
    }
}

Comment: Did you tried with an empty main, without other field declarations? Maybe you did not installed the JRE

Comment: What's the file name? Is it MyClass.java? Do you have a namespace?